# Removing n elements before and after the given number

Tags: c#

can you tell me how to remove n elements before and after the given number in array of integers? For example we have 1 2 2 4 2 2 2 9 and have to remove 2 elements before and after number "4". So it will left 1429. I tried to came up with something, but... nothing.

```
var sequenceOfNums = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToList();
var specials = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
int bombNum = specialBombNum[0];
int power = specialBombNum[1];

for (int i = 0; i < sequenceOfNums.Count; i++) {
  sequenceOfNums.RemoveRange(bombNum, sequenceOfNums.IndexOf(bombNum + power));
  sequenceOfNums.Remove(bombNum);
}
```

Comment: No, we are not here to do your homework for you.  That said, these problems are much easier if you break it down into an algorithm...Consider how you would compare the index of the value to compare against the indexes of those in proximity.

Comment: You do not need a for loop.  You need to fine the '4' then remove a range from index  -2 to index +2.  You also need to check if the remove range isn't negative or exceed the length of the input array.

Comment: It isn't my homework. I'm very new in programming, and I'm trying to understand how the things works. I thought that here is the place where I can ask questions. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var sequenceOfNums = new List<int> {1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 9};

int bombNum = 4;
int power = 2;

//Get the index of the special number
int locationOfSpecialNumber = sequenceOfNums.IndexOf(bombNum);

//Starting from (index of special number - [power]), remove [power] elements
sequenceOfNums.RemoveRange(locationOfSpecialNumber - power, power);

//Starting from (index of special number + 1), remove [power] elements.
//We subtract [power] from the starting index to account for the
//[power] elements we removed in the previous statement
sequenceOfNums.RemoveRange(locationOfSpecialNumber + 1 - power, power);
```